# Trying to make a Discord bot write a msg when someone joins the server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The title pretty much sums it up, but I'll add some more info. I'm trying to make a bot that sends a msg when someone joins. That msg is going to be an embed with some of the info of the new account. The msg needs to be written on 2 different channels and also send a PM to the new user.

I've tried doing this but I don't know why it doesn't send the messages:

```
module.exports = (client) => {

const Discord = require("discord.js")
const moment = require("moment");
require('moment-duration-format');
moment.locale('es');

client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {

const embedGMA = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(" **NEW MEMBER**")
.setDescription('▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬')
.setThumbnail(member.avatarURL())
.addField('USER:',member.tag, true)
.addField('MEMBER:', member.user, true)
.addField('ID:', member.id, true)
.addField('ACCOUNT CREATED:', member.createdAt.toDateString(), true)
.setColor("GREEN")
.addField('NOW WE ARE ' + member.guild.memberCount + ' MEMBERS.', true )
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter(server.name, server.iconURL()) 

member.send("HERE GOES THE PM")
let channel1 = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
let channel2 = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');

channel1.send({ embed : embedGMA})
channel2.send({ embed : embedGMA})
});
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that snippet from / What documentation did you read to code that up?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Spangle I did it after reading some guides about the discordjs v12

Comment: @Lioness100 nope, the bot still works fine but it dont send the messages

Comment: Instead of `client.channels.cache.get()` try to use `client.channels.get("<Channel ID>")`. Does the message get sent to the user's DMs or doesn't it work either?

Comment: @wgumenyuk OP said they were using v12

Comment: @Lioness100 Oh, my bad. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are trying to send an Embed inside an Embed because you declare an Embed here: "const embedGMA = new Discord.MessageEmbed()" and then try to send that as an Embed again here: "channel1.send({ embed : embedGMA})". See [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds) for reference.
To fix it, just try this

EDIT: You need to put the code below into your index.js file (or whatever you named the file to start the bot)

```
            const Discord = require("discord.js");
            /* We can ignore this for the most part as this has nothing to do with the code below
            const moment = require("moment");
            require('moment-duration-format');
            moment.locale('es'); */

            client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
                //here we declare a new Embed
                const embedGMA = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(" **NEW MEMBER**")
                    .setDescription('▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬')
                    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL()) //**
                    .addField('USER:', member.displayName, true) //**
                    .addField('MEMBER:', member.user, true)
                    .addField('ID:', member.id, true)
                    .addField('ACCOUNT CREATED:', member.createdAt.toDateString(), true) // This might give you trouble if you don't have this function defined somewhere
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .addField('NOW WE ARE ' + member.guild.memberCount + ' MEMBERS.', `\u200b`, true) //**
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(server.name, server.iconURL()); // You need to define server somewhere

                member.send("HERE GOES THE PM")
                let channel1 = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
                let channel2 = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
                
                //here we just send the Embed
                channel1.send(embedGMA);
                channel2.send(embedGMA);
            });
```

ps. I also corrected a few of your embed settings, I marked them with //**

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Still it didn't send the embeds to the channels and the PM. It can be affected by other bots that do the same in the server? Bcs the other bot that do the same GuildMemberAdd sends duplicate msgs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any error messages of any kind? Off the top of my head there are a few more things that might affect this. Does your bot have permission to send messages into the channels and is the function actually called when a new member joins the server? The last thing you could check is if your bot has some faulty installation. Create a new project and try to run your code there. Regarding other bots affecting yours, tbh I doubt that the issue is caused by that however I cannot say for certain without knowing what exactly is causing the dublication of messages.

Comment: Nope, the bot works just fine on all of the other commands, also when someone lefts the server it shows correctly another embed with the info of that person. The bot has permission on all ot this channels. I'll try to join the bot to a new server without any more bots and see if it works.

Comment: Let me know how that goes. Have you checked if the function is actually called when someone joins the server? I can confirm that the `client.on('guildMemberAdd',` part works. That definetly sends an embed to the specified channels so the only thing that I can think off right now is that the function is not called when someone joins.

Comment: Well, that might be the problem, bcs idk how to call the function :/

Comment: Ahhhhhh, so we have found the actual problem  You usually call that function in the file that you use to initiate the bot. This is an example https://github.com/Worthy-Alpaca/AJAX/blob/master/src/index.js line 226

Comment: I think I need to check the documentation again, some parts of that code seems like some sort of forgotten dialect for me. Thanks a lot for the help :D

Comment: Well, my index file is a little bit more complicated then what you need to get started with a lot of things that are only needed for my specific use case. But yes, reading the documentation is always a good idea 